# Not all tests of Value-Parameterized tests are run in GoogleTest

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm writing tests with Googletest in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0 and I'm using Value-Parameterization. There is some weird behavior going on that I cannot explain so I hoped someone here might know what is going on.

The fixture class for value-parameterization should create 256 tests for each TEST_P. However, upon running the test for the first time after booting my computer, at least one TEST_P creates less tests than it should. Sometimes it is only 40, sometimes it is 180 or any number just not 256. The tests that do run pass and I don't get an error message. When I hit run again, all tests run as they should.

Here is what the fixture, one TEST_P and the instantiation look like:

```cpp
typedef struct mystruct
{
  mystruct()
  {
    myparam       = new FooStruct;
    bool1         = true;
    bool2         = true;
    bool3         = false;
    bool4         = true;
    bool5         = true;
    bool6         = true;
    uint8_t1      = 0;
    uint8_t2      = 2;
    uint8_t3      = 2;

    int32_t1      = 0;
    int32_t2      = 0;
    int32_t3      = 0;
    int32_t4      = 0;
  }
  ~mystruct()
  {
    delete myparam;
    myparam = NULL;
  }
  void setInt32_t(int32_t newint1, int32_t newint2, int32_t newint3, int32_t newint4)
  {
    int32_t1 = newint1;
    int32_t2 = newint2;
    int32_t3 = newint3;
    int32_t4 = newint4;
  }

  FooStruct *myparam;
  bool    bool1, bool2, bool3, bool4, bool5, bool6;
  uint8_t uint8_t1, uint8_t2, uint8_t3;
  int32_t int32_t1, int32_t2, int32_t3, int32_t4;

}MYSTRUCT_T;

class MyTest : public testing::TestWithParam
< ::std::tr1::tuple<uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, bool, bool, bool, bool> >
{
public:
  MYSTRUCT_T *testparams;

protected:
  virtual void SetUp()
  {
    _Initializer();

    testparams = new mystruct();
    testparams->uint8_t1       = ::std::tr1::get<0>(GetParam());
    testparams->uint8_t2       = ::std::tr1::get<1>(GetParam());
    testparams->uint8_t3       = ::std::tr1::get<2>(GetParam());
    testparams->bool1          = ::std::tr1::get<3>(GetParam());
    testparams->bool2          = ::std::tr1::get<4>(GetParam());
    testparams->bool3          = ::std::tr1::get<5>(GetParam());
    testparams->bool4          = ::std::tr1::get<6>(GetParam());
    //bool5 and bool6 are unused here

  }
  virtual void TearDown()
  {
    delete testparams;
  }
};

TEST_P(MyTest, NameOfTheTest)
{
  testparams->bool1
  ? (testparams->uint8_t3 == 2)
      ? testparams->setInt32_t(0, 0, 0, 0)
      : testparams->limits(1, 1, 1, 1) 
  : (testparams->uint8_t3 == 2)
      ? testparams->setInt32_t(2, 2, 2, 2) 
      : testparams->setInt32_t(3, 3, 3, 3);

  int bar = 0;

  _SetParam(testparams);

  if(!_CheckAndSetParam(testparams, bar))
  {
    FAIL();
    return;
  }

  _DoSomething(bar);

  EXPECT_EQ(0, Global_Var[bar].status());

  int32_t baz = 1;
  _DoMore(bar, baz, testparams->bool2);

  EXPECT_EQ(1, Global_Var[bar].status());
}

using testing::Bool;
using testing::Values;
using testing::Range;

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(InstantiationName, MyTest,
    ::testing::Combine(Range((uint8_t)0, (uint8_t) 4), Range((uint8_t)0, (uint8_t)2), Range((uint8_t)2, (uint8_t)4), Bool(), Bool(), Bool(), Bool()));
```

I am utterly clueless as to why this keeps happening. A colleague just cloned the repository and on his machine the tests ran without a problem first try.
If any further detail or more information about my computer is needed, I am happy to provide it.

**EDIT**: I now noticed that there is an error that is being displayed when this behaviour occurs. Above the Console there is a small status bar (I don't know what it is called or how to best describe it) that continuously shows which test is currently running. When the tests get interrupted it says there: "I/O error: Pipe closed". Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything so far regarding that output. So the question is still unanswered

**Another Edit** : Coming back because the issue has arisen again when I thought it was already solved. I haven't read too much about pipe usage in the GoogleTest Documentation but will do now as I remember seeing it being mentioned at some point. Maybe that will lead me to a clue. The reason, however, I am editing this question again is to describe what I see when the error occurs.

Only one thing is constant among the crashes: the error type which is

> I/O Error: : Pipe closed

Here is how I can invoke it: I edit something in the .cpp where the tests sit and start a run/debug. If there were changes and a build is made, there will likely be a crash.

The crash will after any amount of tests run which seems random. Usually, it happens after around 1800-2600 tests (out of ~2800). With an increasing amount of tests, there seems to be an increased chance in the run crashing. So I assume there will be a point where I can't run the tests anymore because this error will definitely happen. 
In the C/C++ Unit view I see all the tests that ran. All of them have the green check even the last one that seems to make the run crash- at least most of the time. Sometimes it shows the blue "play"-button as if the test were still running, yet in the debug view it states "terminated".

That is about everything I know so far and have observed so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain why you write bool bool1 = new bool(true)?

Comment: @Nico238 The struct is not only used in Value-Parameterized tests and if in any case someone forgets to initialize these values I want them to have these default values.

Comment: you are initializing a bool with the address of a newly allocated bool (which is leaking). All your bool are true (address is not null) whatever the value you set. I can't tell if that is the root cause of your problem but you should fix it.

Comment: @Nico238 thanks for pointing that out. At some point they were pointers and must have forgotten to change this. This could be a reason for the random stops. The value-parameterized tests reinitialize testparams so they will pass but if the newly allocated bool is leaking as you said that may cause an error resulting in the run stopping, correct? EDIT: I just cleaned, rebuilt and relaunched the tests. Unfortunately the problem still persists but thanks for the tip, this was an issue nonetheless.

Comment: "creates less tests" what do you mean precisely? Like it does fail after some test, or it just ends as if there was no more output? Are you running it from Eclipse? Can you try after reboot to run these from command line without IDE, to see if the output really just abruptly ends, or there is some crash/further output? ... and from other end, can you put breakpoint into `Combine` and run the test suite in debugger to see if the combine did at least start 256 tests? Does the code use something from the OS which may take longer to initialize/read/use after cold-start?

Comment: but as with any native machine code, it may be also something completely unrelated completely elsewhere, maybe you can try to narrow down the issue by fixing some of the parameters and combine on smaller set, to see which fixed params produce full combinations set in stable way, and which parameter is making it unstable (if there is such)  (or maybe it's more like timing/amount-of-tests limited)... also what happens if you run it as two tests, one combining for example everything with the second param being 0, second test with 1 (replacing the Range(0,2))... does the first end, second pass?

Comment: @Ped7g With "creates less tests" I mean it just ends as if there were no more tests to run or as you said as if there was no more output. I can try launching it from the command line and putting a breakpoint into ```Combine```. To answer your last question: I don't use any read/write/other OS functions. The tests run fairly fast (usually <0,01s @ 1500 tests)

Comment: @Ped7g I think I worded this badly but there are 7 instantiations of the Testclass (MyTest) of which only the last doesn't run through all combinations. The first 6 will run as expected and the last test will be interrupted at any point. This is not dependant on the test though in my belief. Because I had this problem already 2 days ago and since then I have added tests but the problem persisted. It just shifted to another test

Comment: I would verify first the command line output, maybe it's the IDE which stops collecting output early and doesn't show the end of it, while the output was produced fully in the console I/O. If the output is terminated early even in console, then it's the test runner terminating early... maybe you are just running tests in async thread, and not waiting till all threads finish? Or maybe it's bug in google test itself... but seems to me like the main thread of app ends too early. If that's also the thread where tests run, then the test runner ends early. (or your IDE is lying to you :) )

Comment: You can also try to add something like `sleep(1000);` into `main(..)` (test-unit-main) before exit, to see if that helps, that would signal the tests are run in async threads and the main doesn't wait properly for all of them to finish.  EDIT: just now I did notice the EDIT part ... ok, so now it really boils down what happens, "pipe closed" can be also abrupt exit of the executable, i.e. hard crash or exiting too early. (or bug in console I/O wrapper of the IDE, but I would suspect first my own code, like in 99% of cases :) )

Comment: @Ped7g Right now I believe the issue has been fixed. There were some tests outside of the Value-parameterized tests that didnt have a part of the initialization. However, that didn't lead to an instant crash or even a crash at all in all runs. I am now running from the command line with the ```--gtest_shuffle```flag set to verify that there are no more dependencies. Thanks for your help and especially for recommending running the tests from the command line ;)

Comment: @veryBadProgrammer one thing is, that if your test runner is not flushing stdout for performance reasons, it may end abruptly with output lost in case of crash of the executable... then I would suggest to search google test docs, if there is some API to decide which output stream is used by the test runner for reporting and if there is option to flush/buffer, and switch it to flush after each test, unless it really hurts performance of your tests (it actually may, if you are doing 1500 tests under 0.01s, then with flushed output it may be even 3-5 sec or something like that)

Comment: I need to come back to this to state that the issue is not fixed. With a rising number of tests, the issue has been brought back and now feels like it comes more consistently. I will edit the question for some more detail